# spectrogram axis : plot the frequency on X Axis

Tags: python, audio, spectrogram

I am using the pylab.specgram to plot the spectrogram. As one is aware the specgram always plots freq on the Y axis v/s time on X axis. What I would like to do is to flip the axis such that I can get frequency on the X axis. I tried the following but there is a syntax error.

```
Fs = 44100
w = np.hamming(N)
N = 64
NFFT = int(Fs*0.005)
ov = N - Fs // 1000    

Pxx, freqs, bins, im = pylab.specgram(self.featMatVec, window = w, NFFT=N, Fs=Fs, noverlap = ov, 'yaxis')
plt.ylabel('variable frequency')
plt.xlabel('normalized time')
```

self.featMatVec is a vector created by processing the audio file.

If I do not use the last key word 'yaxis' the specgram is plotted but otherwise there is a syntax error.

Has some one tried this before ? Please suggest any thing that could help.
I cannot post a .jpeg because I am quite new here.

I hope this is clear enough.

thanks !